# Grouping dates in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, loops, time

I have a table of dates and appointments in a MYSQL database.

I'd like to print the contents of this to a file, each date that has an appointment i'd like to group them under it.

e.g

```
<h1>Appontments on 28/01/11<h1>
<p>10am Visit mum</p>
<p>12pm eat cake</p>
```

The format of my table is ID(int), date(DATE), Time(TIME), Description(varchar), Place (varchar)

Whats the best way to go about this, I was thinking of using one loop to find all the dates, then an other loop within that loop to find all the appointments for each date. Is there a more efficient way?

Thanks for your time and excuse my bad explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this is about as optimal as I know how to do it (assuming you have the space in memory, which obviously shouldn't be an issue here):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM appointments GROUP BY `date`";
// Because of the algorithm used to sort dates below, you don't even really
// need the GROUP BY. But what the heck, right?

$result = mysqli_query($mysql, $query);

$appointments = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if (!isset($appointments[$row['date']]))
    {
        $appointments[$row['date']] = array();
    }

    $appointments[$row['date']] []= $row;
}

foreach ($appointments as $date => $items)
{
    echo "<h1>{$date}</h1>";

    echo "<ul>";

    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        echo "<li>{$item['Dime']}: {$item['Description']} " . 
             "@ {$item['Place']}</li>";
    }

    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was wondering what the purpose of the first while loop is, Is it just to load the dates in to an array for sorting in the next section?

Comment: Actually the `while` loop is what does the sorting and grouping; we're basically going through a one-dimensional set of data and adding a dimension to it (dates) so when it comes time to output the data (the outer `foreach` loop), they're already grouped in such a way that it's very easy to use a nested loop to show the groups, and for each group, all of its contents. (If you want to see it in action, add a `var_dump($appointments);` before that outer `foreach` loop so you can see how that array is structured; it might help you understand the purpose of those loops better.)

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I've learned allot this evening, One last question, I was wondering about this line  
    $appointments[$row['date']] []= $row, Iv never saw this syntax used before and cant find anymore info on google. 

thanks!

Comment: So if you dissect that statement a bit, `$row['date']` is just a string, so the left side looks something like `$appointments['2011-04-16']`, which makes sense, since we're interested in indexing our appointments by date. The operator is just a formatting difference from the example shown here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying, which simply assigns a value to an array with its index being the previous highest index + 1. (Basically, a quick way to say "just put this at the end of the array")